# Find ideal of Grassmannian in Macaulay 2

Tags: algebraic-geometry, macaulay2

This question is a technical question about M2. I know that in Macaulay 2 I can use "Grassmannian$(l,k)$" to get ideal of $(l+1)$-plane in $\mathbb{C}^{k+1}$ and the result ideal is in $\mathbb{ZZ}[p_I]$, but how can I work in another field, say, $\mathbb{ZZ}/32003$?

Comment: From `help Grassmannian`: `J = Grassmannian(2,5, CoefficientRing => ZZ/31, Variable => T)`.

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland Thanks a lot. Will try that out!

Comment: Let me provide the answer here:
J=Grassmannian(2,5, CoefficientRing => ZZ/31);
R=use ring J